# PHP AMQP (not phpamqplib) error when using thread

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, amqp, php-amqp

I am trying to make a simple AMQP client into multithread. The following code work if the I don't extend Publish with Thread:

```
<?php

include ('../JS-amqp-include.php');

$mypid = getmypid();

echo "PID: $mypid\n";

class Publish extends Thread {

    private $co;// connection
    private $ch;// channel
    private $ex;// exchange
    private $mypid, $thread_id;

    public function __construct($connection = '') {
        $this->mypid = getmypid();

        $this->co = new AMQPConnection();
        $this->co->setHost(HOST);
        $this->co->setLogin(USER);
        $this->co->setPassword(PASS);
        $this->co->setVHost(VHOST);
        $this->co->connect();           // <-- Fail here!!!!

        $this->ch = new AMQPChannel($this->co);

        $this->ex = new AMQPExchange($this->ch);
        $this->ex->setName(X_DIR);
        $this->ex->setType(XT_DIR);
        $this->ex->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);
        $this->ex->declareExchange();
    }

    public function run($cycle = 10, $input = '') {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $cycle; $i++) {
            $msg = $this->mypid.':'.$input.':'.$i;
            $this->ex->publish($msg);
        }
    }
}

$time_start = microtime(true);

$pub = new Publish();
$pub->run(100, 'thread');
$time_end      = microtime(true);
$time_duration = $time_end-$time_start;
echo "Duration: $time_duration Sec.\n";

?>;
```

Following is output with error:

```
PID: 2276
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'AMQPConnectionException' with message 'Socket error: could not connect to host.' in /home/john/rmq/php/Amqp/JS-amqp-publish-thread.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 /home/john/rmq/php/Amqp/JS-amqp-publish-thread.php(24): AMQPConnection->connect()
#1 /home/john/rmq/php/Amqp/JS-amqp-publish-thread.php(45): Publish->__construct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/john/rmq/php/Amqp/JS-amqp-publish-thread.php on line 24
```

Anyone has idea why this happen or how to fix?

Rabbitmq is running at HOST.

The program works perfectly if 'extends Thread' is removed from class Publish declaration. The above code is not even using thread yet. I just extend the class and it break.

**System Info**

OS: Ubuntu 15.10

Rabbitmq-c (apt-get install)

librabbitmq-dev:amd64 0.5.2-2 amd64   AMQP client library written in C - Dev Files
librabbitmq1:amd64    0.5.2-2 amd64   AMQP client library written in C

I follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-zts-support-on-ubuntu-14-04) to re-compile Ubuntu PHP package to support ZTS.

PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.2 (cli)

Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

PHP module

amqp     1.6.0   stable

pthreads 2.0.10  stable

Comment: 1. Is service of AMQP runned on HOST? 2. Is HOST contains correct value?

Comment: Yes, rabbitmq is running. If I remove "extends Thread" from the class, the program works without issue.

Comment: Hi, provide php-amqp version, librabbitmq version, php version, OS version and a way you installed php-amqp and librabbitmq.

Comment: @zaq178miami I updated question with system. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Can you establish connection to rabbitmq outside Thread class?

Comment: @zaq178miami if I move the connect outside thread class and pass the connection into the construction, then channel will fail.

Comment: But can you establish connection with given credentials?

Comment: @zaq178miami yes. credentials is correct.

Comment: Note, that with php-amqp you can't share anything between threads, so normally you keep separate connection per thread. Give a look on pthreads examples, like this one - https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/examples/MySQLi.php.

Comment: p.s.: good reading from recent /r/php: http://blog.madewithlove.be/post/thread-carefully/

Comment: @zaq178miami Connection is already per thread.